# PyMongo find by multiple values

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In Mongo shell, one can `find` documents for multiple values in the same field by

`coll.find({blah: {$in: ["foo", "bar"]}});`

Just wondering how to do this in PyMongo? Tried this but doesn't work:

`coll.find({'blah': ['foo', 'bar']})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add quotes around field name and `$in` operator:

```
coll.find({'blah': {'$in': ["foo", "bar"]}})
```